# Saving Bitmap as PNG on WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to save a bitmap to my isolated storage as a png file. I found a library on Codeplex called ImageTools which people have been recommending but when i try it and attempt to open the file it says that its corrupt. Any know what i am doing wrong?

```
private static void SaveImageToIsolatedStorageAsPng(BitmapImage bitmap, string fileName)
{
    //convert to memory stream
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    WriteableBitmap writableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
    writableBitmap.SaveJpeg(memoryStream, bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

    //encode memory stream as PNG
    ExtendedImage image = new ExtendedImage();
    image.SetSource(memoryStream);

    PngEncoder encoder = new PngEncoder();

    //Save to IsolatedStorage
    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    using (var writeStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, store))
    {
        encoder.Encode(image, writeStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it you want to convert to a slower format in the first place? if the image is JPEG, you don't gain anything by converting it to PNG. And viewing PNG is slower than JPEG.

Comment: The format i needs to be in PNG

Comment: maybe he needs transparency or lossless compression?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're attempting to convert the JPEG memory stream into PNG. That will make it corrupt - you should save the Bitmap directly to PNG.

I haven't tried this particular task with the [imagetools library](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/),  but if you [see John Papa's blog](http://johnpapa.net/saving-snapshots-to-png-in-silverlight-4-and-the-webcam), it looks like you need to call the `ToImage` extension method on your `WriteableBitmap` which is provided as part of ImageTools. Then you can use the encoder to take this image and write out to your open stream.

```
var img = bitmap.ToImage();
var encoder = new PngEncoder();
using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, store))
{
    encoder.Encode(img, stream);
    stream.Close();
}
```

Comment: I see, i'm not sure how i can get bitmap to a stream any other way. could u set the ExtendedImage's source to the IsolatedFileStream?

Comment: Ah - doing a quick search, it seems that's not very well documented - I've updated the answer.

Comment: If you use the directive "using" you don't have to close the stream explicity with "stream.close()" as the own directive closes and disposes it.