# Improving JPG screenshot quality when saving to media lib Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, screenshot, media

I am using the following code to take the screenshot of my app. However even though quality is set at 100, the final screenshot is still looks blurry. Any suggestions on how I can improve the image quality.

```
    public static void SaveJPGToLib(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        WriteableBitmap bmpCurrentScreenImage = new WriteableBitmap((int)element.ActualWidth, (int)element.ActualHeight);
        bmpCurrentScreenImage.Render(element, new MatrixTransform());
        bmpCurrentScreenImage.Invalidate();

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Save the picture to the Windows Phone media library.
            bmpCurrentScreenImage.SaveJpeg(stream, bmpCurrentScreenImage.PixelWidth, bmpCurrentScreenImage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            string filename = "screenshots\\" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ".jpg";
            new MediaLibrary().SavePicture(filename, stream);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Saved in your media library!", "Done", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
```

Notice the difference between the original and resulting screenshot.

Original quality

[image: original]

Screenshot

[image: screenshot taken via code]

Comment: have you tried png format?

Comment: I thought Media Lib does not support PNG?

Comment: using PngEncoder, sample in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378946/saving-bitmap-as-png-on-wp7

Comment: Yes I think I can use that to save to IsolatedStorage but I thought I cannot save PNG to Windows Phone Media Library which what I am trying to do.