# Is there any way to save an image object as png to keep the transparent colour

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I have not found a way up until now to save an image as png into the isolated storage. The only save for images i found was the `SaveJpeg()`, but that way i loose the transperancy of the image. Does anyone know of another method that allows you to save the `BitMapImage` as .png to the `IsolatedStorage`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving Bitmap as PNG on WP7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378946/saving-bitmap-as-png-on-wp7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ImageTools supports](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/) working with PNGs (encoding and decoding)

Plus, it has been asked a number of times... [Saving Bitmap as PNG on WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378946/saving-bitmap-as-png-on-wp7)

Comment: thats all great but if u use the save to jpeg u loose the transparent colours and converting it back doesnt help then because the corners are black now.

Comment: That's kind of obvious, because JPEG doesn't allow transparancies. You need to encode it to PNG and then save the stream to Isolated Storage. Maybe I don't understand your problem, but it's fairly simple.

Comment: I missread the answer.  Days been to long. Im going to give that a try

Answer (score 0):

My logic was incorrect. I was attempting to take a jpeg and then convert it to png which ended up in me loosing my transparency. I overlooked the fact that the "screenshot" feature i was using saved the stream to jpeg and then reused it. My mistake, I need to figure out how i can take a screenshot as png